# Adapting a perl script to convert bibitem to BibTeX

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed, bibliography

I wrote a journal article some time ago that, luckily, was accepted. The publisher kindly sent me the LaTeX file derived from the article. I now want to include the LaTeX code into my PhD thesis. It is fully working except for the bibliography. The publisher included the bibliography in an `\thebibliography` environment and used `\bibitem` for each entry. The bibliography has the following format:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{}
{\AA}gren, A., Buffam, I., Berggren, M., Bishop, K., Jansson, M., and Laudon,
H.: Dissolved organic carbon characteristics in boreal streams in a
forest-wetland gradient during the transition between winter and summer, J.
Geophys. Res.-Biogeo., 113, G03031, \href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2007JG000674}{doi:10.1029/2007JG000674}, 2008.

\bibitem{}
Alewell, C., Lischeid, G., Hell, U., and Manderscheid, B.: High temporal
resolution of ion fluxes in semi-natural ecosystems -- gain of information or
waste of resources? Biogeochemistry, 69, 19--35,
\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/B:BIOG.0000031029.46798.7f}{doi:10.1023/B:BIOG.0000031029.46798.7f}, 2004.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I now want to include the bibliography into my thesis using BibTeX/BibLaTeX. Therefore, I need to convert each \bibitem into one `.bib` file. I already tried the website converter at text2bib but it gave me a lot of errors (not recognizing author and year published). I also ran the tex2bib-Perl script without any success.

How can I adapt the Perl [script](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2108381/tex2bib.pl) or writing some new importer using Python, Awk or Sed? I don't have much experience in using Awk and Sed but they should be able to do the trick. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2108381/testfile.txt), you can find some example data.

A few hours of searching was to no avail.

Comment: See also [Convert .bbl file to .bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203177/24422)

Comment: The \bibitem entries are not in the .bbl file. I already checked that.

Comment: If you are looking for someone to convert or write a script for you, the question is too broad, unfortunately. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help with specific and focussed problems.

Comment: I suggest to just learn how to use LaTeX and BibTeX, as it's worth knowing anyway. Write the BibTeX file yourself. (Yes, even if you have 100 references). Many publishers' websites offer BibTeX entries for easy citation. Look up each paper you cite (you have the doi numbers), download the BibTeX entry, and append them all in a `.bib` file (they all go in one file). Then tweak the fields as needed (I'd never use all the fields they give you). Or, you could just label the fields in the file you already have. Tweaking Perl scripts or meditating over awk and sed commands is a waste of time.

Comment: That is rather unstructured data, so you will need pretty good heuristics. The colon seems to separate authors and title, and the `href` element is clearly marked, but otherwise? Lists of random page numbers? `G03031`? I tend to agree with @e0k: do it by hand.

Comment: I ended up editing the .bib file by hand. There were 64 citations and it took me about 1,5 hours. Luckily, I had doi numbers for most citations. That made the procedure a lot faster. But thanks a lot for your hints and comments.